# C++ error: 'iterator is not a type'

Tags: c++, templates

Here's my code:

```
template <typename container_type>
void transfer(container_type container, iterator begin, iterator end) {
    for (; begin != end; begin++)
        if (!element_in_container(container, *begin))
            container.insert(iterator, *begin);
}
```

I get the error `'iterator is not a type'`.

I tried adding `std::` or `container_type::` before `iterator`, didn't help. I tried defining the template as `template <typename container_type<typename T> >` and the iterators as `container_type<T>::iterator`, no luck. What's wrong?

Comment: how about `typename container_type::iterator` ?

Comment: Indeed, `iterator` is not a type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: `container` should be passed by reference.

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean the following

```
template <typename container_type>
void transfer( container_type container, typename container_type::iterator begin, 
                                         typename container_type::iterator end) {
```

Take into account that in any case your function is wrong because after inserting an element in the container iterators can be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried adding `std::` or `container_type::` before iterator, didn't
>   help.

`container_type::iterator` is a dependent name, therefore you need the `typename` keyword before it to treat it as a type (`typename container_type::iterator`). That is explained in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).